# Error invalid method declaration; return type required

Tags: java, jcreator

I am receiving this type of error within jcreator but am unsure on how to fix. Here is the code line

```
public Account(String name, double balance)
{
    this.name = name;

    return name;

    if(balance>0.0)

    this.balance = balance;

    return balance;     

}
```

Comment: You're inside a constructor. Therefore you're not allowed to return something.

Comment: Also note that even if this were a normal method, you've got two return statements that return different types, so it still wouldn't compile.

Comment: For getting the basics of a language, you may better go for a basic tutorial and some examples. This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPvGqX-TXP0 . And also this site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your method name would have to be changed to

```
public double Account(String name, double balance){
//code here
}
```

and if you are not creating an object or class file to go off of...aka if your calling the method standalone from the static main method 
like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

double a = Account(test1, 123);
}
```

you would need to make the method name with `static`, which would look like this:

```
public static double Account(String name, double balance){
//code here
}
```